# Get IP ADDRESS in Express and GraphQL

Tags: typescript, express, graphql

I have a question. So, I recently switched from `rest` to `gql`, and I have a problem.
In `rest` I got `ip address` by `req.ip`. I tried to do it in `resolve()` function and it wasn't working `(undefined)`. I searched the web and found this:

```
const server = new GraphQLServer({
  context: context => ({
    ...context,
    db,
    userIp: maybeGetUserIpAddress(context.request),
  }),
});

const maybeGetuserIpAddress = (request): ?string => {
  const headers = request.headers;
  if (!headers) return null;
  const ipAddress = headers['x-forwarded-for'];
  if (!ipAddress) return null;
  return ipAddress;
};
```

But it returns `undefined` too.

So, my questions are:

```
1. Is this because I'm hosting my server locally?
2. What is wrong with the code
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's because you are on localhost req.ip && req.socket.remoteAddress won't do the trick.

You can use this instead.

(req -> express.Request)

```
  const ip = require('ipware')().get_ip(req)?.clientIp || req?.ip || req?.socket?.remoteAddress || '127.0.0.1'
```